# How can i use component methods in other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I created a notification component. I want to use it in other components

How can i use the `this.addNotification()` in my navbar.js?  I tried many ways but none was working, so maybe someone here knows the best way to do this. I will be glad for any help!

```
   //Notifications.js
import React from "react";
import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component";
import "react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css";

export default class Notifications extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addNotification = this.addNotification.bind(this);
    this.notificationDOMRef = React.createRef();
  }

  addNotification() {
    this.notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({
      title: "Awesomeness",
      message: "Awesome Notifications!",
      type: "success",
      insert: "top",
      container: "top-right",
      animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
      animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
      dismiss: { duration: 2000 },
      dismissable: { click: true }
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-content">
        <ReactNotification ref={this.notificationDOMRef} />
        <button ref={this.addNotification} className="btn btn-primary">
          Add Awesome Notification
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


//Navbar.js
// I want to use the notifications here, but i don't know how
// this.addNotification() - > this is working in the notifications file, `but not here`

import React from 'react';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import LoginModal from './LoginModal';
import User from './User';

// i just import the class 
import Notifications from './Notifications';

export default class MyNavbar extends User {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.toggleDropDown = this.toggleDropDown.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      userName: this.getUserLogin(),
      userEmail: this.getUserEmail(),
      firstTime: this.getFirstTime(),
      dropdownOpen: false,
      info:""
    };
  }

showError(){
 this.addNotification()
// I want something like this, but i don't know how to do this
 }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  toggleDropDown() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
 }


  render(props) {
    return (
      <div>
       <Container>

        <Navbar color="da" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">Pies Fajny Jest</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          {this.state.userName ?
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggleDropDown}>
       <DropdownToggle className="btn btn-danger" caret>
        {this.state.userName}
       </DropdownToggle>
       <DropdownMenu>
         <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
         <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
         <DropdownItem disabled>Action (disabled)</DropdownItem>
         <DropdownItem divider />
         <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
         <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
         <DropdownItem onClick={ () => this.logout(this) }>Wyloguj</DropdownItem>
       </DropdownMenu>
     </Dropdown>
              </Nav>
             :
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem className="LoginRegister" >
              <LoginModal
              buttonLabel="Zaloguj się"
              title="Logowanie"
              inputSubmit="Zaloguj się"
              />
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem className="LoginRegister" >
              <LoginModal
              buttonLabel="Zarejestruj się"
              title="Rejestracja"
              inputSubmit="Zarejestruj się"
              register="register"
              />
                  </NavItem>
                  </Nav>}
              </Collapse>
            </Navbar>
           </Container>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Pass the method as a props.

Comment: Can you explain? I'm new in react @Sohan

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the method as props eg

```
<Notifications addNotification={this.addNotification} />
```

an when you console this.props.addNotification you get that function there in Notifications.js

Comment: i tried this, but i want to use the notifications in my methods, so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, but I think the best way to create notifications is to use listeners. But I think this will work. 
Also avoid to use ".bind()" on constructor, instead use arrow functions.

```
//Notifications.js
import React from "react";
import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component";
import "react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css";

// Create a variable 
let notificationDOMRef = null

// export this function and import where you want to use
export const addNotification = () => {
    notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({
    title: "Awesomeness",
    message: "Awesome Notifications!",
    type: "success",
    insert: "top",
    container: "top-right",
    animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
    animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
    dismiss: { duration: 2000 },
    dismissable: { click: true }
    });
}

export default class Notifications extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ReactNotification ref={ref => notificationDOMRef = ref} />
        );
    }
}


//Navbar.js
// I want to use the notifications here, but i don't know how
// this.addNotification() - > this is working in the notifications file, `but not here`

import React from 'react';
import {
Collapse,
Navbar,
NavbarToggler,
NavbarBrand,
Nav,
NavItem,
NavLink,
UncontrolledDropdown,
Dropdown,
DropdownToggle,
DropdownMenu,
DropdownItem, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import LoginModal from './LoginModal';
import User from './User';

// just import the class and the function
import Notifications, { addNotification } from './Notifications';

export default class MyNavbar extends User {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.toggleDropDown = this.toggleDropDown.bind(this);

    this.state = {
    isOpen: false,
    userName: this.getUserLogin(),
    userEmail: this.getUserEmail(),
    firstTime: this.getFirstTime(),
    dropdownOpen: false,
    info:""
    };
}

showError(){
    // you can use here
    addNotification()
}

toggle() {
    this.setState({
    isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
}

toggleDropDown() {
    this.setState({
    dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
}


render(props) {
    return (
    <div>
    // You need to render your component
    <Notifications />
    <Container>

        <Navbar color="da" light expand="md">
        <NavbarBrand href="/">Pies Fajny Jest</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
        {this.state.userName ?
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggleDropDown}>
    <DropdownToggle className="btn btn-danger" caret>
        {this.state.userName}
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem disabled>Action (disabled)</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />
        <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={ () => this.logout(this) }>Wyloguj</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
            </Nav>
            :
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem className="LoginRegister" >
            <LoginModal
            buttonLabel="Zaloguj się"
            title="Logowanie"
            inputSubmit="Zaloguj się"
            />
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem className="LoginRegister" >
            <LoginModal
            buttonLabel="Zarejestruj się"
            title="Rejestracja"
            inputSubmit="Zarejestruj się"
            register="register"
            />
                </NavItem>
                </Nav>}
            </Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </Container>
        </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work setting the variable notificationDOMRef on constructor, in this case override the method 'componentDidMount' and set it

Comment: I tried to execute the method showError() and i got this:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null

export const addNotification = () => {
 ->   notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({
    title: "Awesomeness",
    message: "Awesome Notifications!",
    type: "success",
    insert: "top",
    container: "top-right",
    animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
    animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
    dismiss: { duration: 2000 },
    dismissable: { click: true }
    });
}

Comment: Beacause on constructor when you set the variable you didn't rendered your component yet, that's why you should override the method componentDidMount, or use this ref={ ref => notificationDOMRef = ref} on ReactNotification

Comment: The second one is the best way to do it

Comment: can you show me the code? as i said im newbie and it's hard to figure it out for me

Comment: i tried do to this but im doing it wrong propably ;d

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute the method showError() and i got this:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null

this line: notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({

Comment: You should comment on answer, do not add new answer.